# on adding new fields app crashed

Tags: android

I'm writing a following query

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT fatkgrate FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME3 + " WHERE " +
                                "cast(" + msnf + " as integer) between  fromsnf AND tosnf " +
                                "and  cast(" + mfat + " as integer) between  fromfat AND tofat " +
                                " "
                        ,null );
```

working fine but when i add cattle in my where as following my app crash

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT fatkgrate FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME3 + " WHERE " +
                                "cast(" + msnf + " as integer) between  fromsnf AND tosnf " +
                                "and  cast(" + mfat + " as integer) between  fromfat AND tofat " +
                                "and cattle = cast(" + mcattlez + " as text) "
                        ,null );
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: show your logcat.

Comment: it has been solved

Comment: sounds great keep working.